# DL expression generation using OWL API

Tags: java, owl-api, description-logic

I need to generate DL expression from `OWLObject` in OWL API. For now, I am using `DLSyntaxObjectRenderer` like:

```
DLSyntaxObjectRenderer obj = new DLSyntaxObjectRenderer();
```

The problem is that the DL expressions that are generated only contain the labels of the resources (e.g. `Awning ⊔ Door ⊔ Gate ⊔ Shutter ⊔ Window`). While these are syntactically valid DL expressions, for implementation sake, I need the IRIs of the atomic entities so that I can load the expression using OWL API after without having to load the entire ontology.

**How can I achieve this ?**

Comment: Which OWL-API version? What did you try? Did you try to set an overridden `ShortFormProvider` into this `OWLObjectRenderer` (both classes are since 2.2.0)? Are you sure it prints labels, not IRI local name ?

Comment: Sorry for delay in replying, i'm current using OWL API 5.1.10. I didn't know about `OWLObjectRenderer`. As mentioned above, i'm using `DLSyntaxObjectRenderer` and rendering the expression using its `render` method

Comment: thanks for the hints, managed to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ShortFormProvider` determines the rendering of entities. It has several implementation such as `ManchesterOWLSyntaxPrefixNameShortFormProvider`, `QNameShortFormProvider`, `SimpleShortFormProvider`. For example, the following code use the `DLSyntaxObjectRenderer` and make it render DL expressions using the IRI of entities,

```
obj = new DLSyntaxObjectRenderer();
ShortFormProvider shortFormProvider = new ShortFormProvider() {
                @Override
                public String getShortForm(OWLEntity owlEntity) {
                    return owlEntity.getIRI().getIRIString();
                }
            };
obj.setShortFormProvider(shortFormProvider);
```

To render an expression `exp`, simply use `obj.render(exp)`